# How To Solve Equation With Division By Zero

Tags: divisibility

I have an equation that I've been given the task to solve as part of a course I am doing:

```
x = (y * a - z * b) / (u * (b - a))
```

This has worked fine, but in the only question I have left, `b - a = 0`, in which case `u * (b - a) = 0` and therefore I am trying to divide by 0.

I am literally tearing my hair out trying to solve this - how do I rearrange it so that I can calculate `x` when `b - a = 0`?

Btw, I am happy to state that this is *unsolvable* in these circumstances, but I must be certain that it is before I submit my work.

Comment: Given that you are given that function,  you are also implicitly given the guarantee that the denominator is non zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = (y * a - z * b) / (u * (b - a))
```

comes from something like
$$u(b-a)x=ya-zb$$
if $b-a=0$ that is if $b=a$ the LHS becomes $0$
$$0=(y-z)b$$
Now we have two possibilities:

1. if RHS is zero,e.g. if $y=z$, the equation is indeterminate and has infinite solutions
2. if RHS is not zero the equation is impossible and there is no solution.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Whenever people write $x/y$, there's almost always an implicit assumption that $y \neq 0$. In your example, $x$ is *undefined* when $b-a=0$; it simply does not make sense to ask what the value of the function would be there.

Comment: I've rearranged an equation to end up with the one giving me the problem.  I think I'll post a new question with the equation I've rearranged to see if someone can advise what I may have done incorrectly.  There is _definitely_ an answe to the question I am told, so perhaps the issue is with my work

Comment: @Martin Okay, good luck with solving your problem. Make sure to post all of the necessary details needed for people to help you.

Comment: @Martin, in that case you'll have to tackle the case $a = b$ separately (before rearranging).